# Can the correlation or covariance of two variables be translated into a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, covariance, copula

Question: Can the correlation coefficient (r or r²) or the covariance (Cov(X,Y)) be somehow translated into a probability distribution for the dependent variable?

Example: If r²=0.8 for two random variables X and Y in a data set, in which X is the independent variable and Y is the dependent variable, how can I obtain the probability of finding Y=a given X=b? Is it possible? If not, is there any way of calculating it?

Comment: It is not enough information to uniqely define a distribution. but you should look into copulas.  Search this site for "copula".

Comment: I can't infer your $X, Y$ from that information. So, you can't either. Think about it: in what sense could the distribution information be encapsulated in that single result?

Comment: There are only three ways to uniquely identify a probability distribution: (1) MGF ; (2) CDF; (3) the PDF is equal at all values, except perhaps a set with measure 0.

Comment: Why is this marked as "unclear" when the three comments all seem to say that the answer is "no"?